# WhatsApp not found in Store

Tags: store, whatsapp

I already installed WhatsApp on my Lumia 525. Today when I searched for WhatsApp in the Store nothing turned up. When I go to my app and check for updates, I am displayed with a message that it's not available for my phone. Where is WhatsApp?

Comment: Seems for 625 also., found this. http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Phone-Applications/Whatsapp-not-available-for-Nokia-Lumia-625/m-p/2626660&sa=U&ei=KYZ4U5nYDJahugT9mYG4Cw&ved=0CAsQFjAA&sig2=SFv_VMoRBuYcA4JUWOSdYQ&usg=AFQjCNHm2iK2W_XpBsvYWAStRJNsOiFomQ

Comment: WhatsApp is **now back** in the store

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WhatsApp has been [temporarily pulled from the Store](http://www.neowin.net/news/whatsapp-pulled-from-the-windows-phone-store) (starting the evening of May 17, 2014). A new, improved version has been published on the store on the 31st of May.

Updates:

I've read that WhatsApp is still available for WP 7.x devices, but can't confirm this myself.

This is [not the first](http://www.whatsappen.com/news/2012/08/03/whatsapp-disappeared-from-wp-marketplace/) time WhatsApp has been temporarily pulled from the store.

Rumor has it WhatsApp might be preparing a [paid version](http://www.wpcentral.com/whatsapp-pulled-windows-phone-marketplace) of the app.

[Joe Belfiore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Belfiore) tweeted two updates on the situation: For those w Q’s on Whatsapp: they pinged us about an issue that popped on notifications, we’re working with them on a fix. More info soon. Ps - the notifications core in wp8.1 is different than wp8. The WhatsApp issue is in wp8 upd3. How's your wp8.1 notifications experience?— joebelfiore (@joebelfiore) [1](https://twitter.com/joebelfiore/statuses/469495987988209665) [2](https://twitter.com/joebelfiore/statuses/469496557541146625)

Comment: Thanks.., there were no clue in web so far i know.,

Comment: And don't delete it if you already have it installed :)

Comment: Small update: http://wmpoweruser.com/whatsapp-will-be-restored-soon-says-microsoft